# Codeigniter pagination libraries

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I'm looking for codeigniter pagination library, where my pages would be displayed like this:

> 1 2 3 4 5 ... 11 12 13 14 ... 27 28 29

I mean with adjacent. Where can I find it? My php knowledge is not so good to rewrite pagination library

Comment: go and google it for me, I'm searching it for ~2 weeks..

Answer (score 0):

use codeigniter user guide [Pagination](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html)

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer, there is no information about my question.

Answer (score 0):

try this code. You can change the logic according to your needs:-

```
let totalcount = Math.ceil(JSON.parse(this.response).total / limit), HTML = "", j = 1;
(page > 3) ? HTML += "<button>...</button>" : null;
(page === 1) ? page = page + 1 : (page === totalcount) ? page = (totalcount - 1) : page;
for (let i = Math.max(2, page - j); i <= Math.min(totalcount - 1, page + j); i++) {
    HTML += "<button onclick=loadDoc(" + i + ")>" + (i) + "</button>"
}
(page < 10) ? HTML += "<button>...</button>" : null;
HTML += "<button onclick=loadDoc(" + totalcount + ")>" + (totalcount) + "</button>";
document.getElementById("pager").innerHTML = HTML;
```